# How to draw the Curve for this Normal Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

This is not my homework question, I am preparing for the GRE test and stuck on it.

**Question)** The random variable X is normally distributed. The values 650 and 850 are at the 60th and 90th percentile of the distribution of X respectively. 
What is the value at the 75th percentile of the distribution of X?

**My Attempt:**

First of all, I have no idea how to draw the curve for this question, because according to the GRE book, there should be the mean value as well as the standard deviation given to draw the curve. 
Anyway, 75th percentile is exactly between the 60th and the 90th percentile, 60th + 90th / 2 = 75th values.

Therefore, the answer should be 650 + 850 / 2 = 750.

But according to someone this is an incorrect answer and it cannot be determined without drawing the curve.

How can i draw the curve for this question, and why my answer is incorrect ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the Gaussian curve is not linear, and you cannot use the middle point. Since it is convex, it is less than the simple average. What instruments you have to evaluate the answer, and how much it needs to be precise?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we can assume that the problem is solved by now.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to draw the curve.  You need to determine the mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ of the Normal Distribution since $\mu, \sigma$ define it completely.  You then use $\mu, \sigma$ to determine the 75th percentile.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not a uniform distribution, therefore the relation is not linear. What you can do instead  is use the $z$-scores to find the exact value. Do brush up on your statistics beforehand. The  $60th$ percentile was $650$. Using $z$ score tables, $z$ score at $60th$ percentile is $0.253$ and at $90th$ is $1.283$. The mean plus $0.253$ times standard deviation gives $650$ and the mean plus $1.282$ times standard deviation gives $850$. You can use those two as a system of linear equations and solve simultaneously to get the mean and standard deviation as $600.8$ and $194.4$ respectively. Then to find the value at $75th$ percentile, it’s the mean ($600.8$) plus $0.624$ ($z$ score) times the standard deviation ($194.4$) giving $731.85$. If you could draw the curve as well, you could reason that at the $75th$ percentile, the area between the $60th$ percentile and the $75th$ percentile should be the same as from $75th$ to $90th$, but since the height of the curve is higher at sixty and trails off, the $75th$ percentile will be closer to $60th$ than $90$, hence the value would be less than the midpoint value between the $60th$ and $90th$. Would have typed the equations but I’m using my phone.